# Async each series not showing proper result, display one element of array instead of all elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I am newbie to Nodejs and using async.eachSeries to iterate the array, when the array has four elements it only display one element in final response and also add new variable to array called ”payment type”,its not assigning also.
I want to display all elements in array as a final output. Below is the code and is this approach is correct? What I have seen also it first displays all elements in console.log but in postman it shows only one data. How to fix this issue to send all array to postman after the completion of async.eachSeries.

Code:

```
let members=[];
 Utils.async.each(response,(rowTrainers, callback) => {
                        var result=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rowTrainers));
             rowTrainers.dataValues.payment_type =  "Cashfree";
                            return callback();
                         }) ,err=>{
                            if(err){
                                console.error("Error: ", err);
                                cb(err, []); 
                            }else{
              members=rowTrainers;
                            Utils.sendResponse(1, rowTrainers , "success", q)

                            }
                        }
```

Actual Output:

```
{
    "message": [
        {
             "firstName": “Abc”,
            "lastName": "xyzzy”,
       “age”:24
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "message": [
        {
            "firstName": “Abc”,
            "lastName": “xyzzy”,
        “age”:24,
“payment_type”:”Online”
        },
{
            "firstName": “def”,
            "lastName": “pmo”,
“age”:23,
“payment_type”:”Online”

        },
{
            "firstName": “per”,
            "lastName": “abc”,
      “age”:23,
“payment_type”:”Online”

        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try for the following:

```
  let members=[];
 Utils.async.each(response,(rowTrainers, callback) => {
    var result=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rowTrainers));
                rowTrainers.dataValues.payment_type =  "Cashfree";
                    members.push(rowTrainers);
                    callback();
                    } ,err=>{
                    if(err){
                        console.error("Error: ", err);
                        cb(err, []); 
                    }else{              
                    Utils.sendResponse(1, members , "success", q)

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply it working but not printing in else loop.if you print  before err block it shows the data.

Comment: @Nits6029 There is some syntax error in the code. I have edited the code . Check whether it's working?? See the `)` ending

Comment: @Nits6029 what is printing in else block??

Comment: @Subburaj.It's not going to else block.just print hello world in console.log is not showing.

Comment: @Nits6029 The its going into err block, SO print and see what's the error and resolve it. Also accept the answer if it solved the problem

Comment: @Subburaj.Its not going into err block,I just printed hello world after err before if loop, not showing data

Comment: I am just checking side by side in my code just to check whether is going into else block or not.

Comment: @Nits6029 The above code should work. Accept it so that it will helpful for others.